# Склеивание изображений aiogram python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

День добрый , помогите пожалуйста найти решение

Суть такая: у меня есть телеграмм бот и шаблон фото , нужно сделать так чтобы пользователь когда отправлял фото боту , бот выдавал ему фото изменённое ( тоесть на мой шаблон накладывается то что отправил пользователь).

Answer (score 0):

С помощью Aiogram ты можешь только получить от пользователя фото и отправить ему. Обрабатывает фото твоя функция.
Алгоритм такой:

1. Получаешь от пользователя фото и сохраняешь
2. Сохраняешь в состоянии aiogram id пользователя
3. Твоя функция обрабатывает фото
4. Бот отправляет этому пользователю обработанное фото